# Beyond Compare as default diff tool in Eclipse when using Mercurial?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, beyondcompare

Is there any way to make Beyond Compare 3 the default diff tool in Eclipse?
I'm using the Mercurial plugin and would like to use BC3 for diffing files and handling merge conflicts.
I'm only able to find solutions when it comes to CVS or SVN when searching this site.

Comment: Do you mean THE "Mercurial plugin" by Vectrace? Looking at its latest source (utils/CompareUtils.java), there doesn't seem to be a way. There's only an option to use external tool to resolve conflict. You could hack the plugin, or hack the Beyond CVS plugin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/beyondcvs/) to use hg.

Comment: Sorry I meant MercurialEclipse. I've set the option for using external tools for handling merge conflicts (and it does), but whenever I try to diff files through Eclipse the builtin tool is executed. Hack the plugin is an option, but I'm not sure where to begin. Didn't even know it was open source. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See the following query for discussion on external diff tool for Mercurial Eclipse.

- http://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/310/external-diff-tool

It suggests that standard approach for setting up external diff tool should suffice. So setting up ".hgrc" should work.

Since this is no different from any other setup, you can test it by using hg commands in shell. See if that throws any errors and then check out with eclipse.

The setting for external merge tool is available in the plugin settings.

- http://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Installation_and_Configuration#main-preferences

[edit: with hgrc]

This will work when you use command line.

> The following "[**ExtdiffExtension**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension)" extension should help.

The extdiff Mercurial extension allows you to use external programs to compare revisions, or revision with working dir. The external diff programs are called with a configurable set of options and two non-option arguments: paths to directories containing snapshots of files to compare.

Comment: The plugin settings only allows me to use an external tool for resolving conflicts not regular two-way diff. However setting up the hgrc might work, even though I've failded so far. :-)
Scooter software has a setup here (http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?c=kb_vcs.php) that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MdaG: If you want to use external diff tool. I would suggest that instead configure your command line to use the external diff. It will at least help you to overcome the limitation of MercurialEclipse.

Comment: I currently use TortoiseHg which boots up BC when I want to compare files and it works fine. I'll check out the ExtDiffExtension for the command line. :-)
But I take it MercurialEclipse doesn't support external tools for diffing at the time of writing this.

Comment: @MdaG: Yes. So far my exploration has yielded no way of doing that. But I have always preferred the command line way of setting up so it had not been a issue with me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Beyond Compare Eclipse Plugin (Beyond CVS) which would provide this functionality.

Cheers!!!